# Plotting bars as a line matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I would like to make a bar plot in matplotlib, but instead of bars I would like it to have lines (see picture at the bottom please for an example)[image] It is from this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10529

When trying to search for the solution, I only find tutorials or posts about how to plot a line in a bar graph, but that is not what I want.

Does somebody know the correct term I should use when searching for this? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try to change the width of the bars? Then your bars would look like lines.

Comment: As @Rabinzel suggested, you are looking for [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) with the argument *width* set to some non-zero value.

Comment: There is a built-in [`plt.stem`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html) function that does almost the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can play with line width and alpha values to achieve what you want. Note also you need to take care of the ticks values.
considering the values where:

[0.22, 0.17, 0.13, 0.10, 0.08, 0.07, 0.065, 0.06, 0.055, 0.05]

You can do the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [0.22, 0.17, 0.13, 0.10, 0.08, 0.07, 0.065, 0.06, 0.055, 0.05]
plt.figure()
ticks = []
# tip from Rabinzel to use 1 in enumerate instead of adding +1 to num
for num, value in enumerate(values, 1):
    plt.plot([num, num],[0, value], lw=5, alpha=0.4, c='b')
    plt.scatter(num, value,c='b')
    ticks.append(num)
plt.xlabel("Span Length (# of Words)")    
plt.ylabel("Sampling Probability")
plt.xticks(ticks)
plt.ylim(0,0.25)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: you can pass a 2nd argument to `enumerate` which defines the `start` of your `num`. `for num, value in enumerate(values, 1)`, then you don't need to add 1 everytime you use it.

Comment: @Rabinzel, really thanks for the tip, didn't knew that I will update the answer considering this

Comment: Hey Rabinzel and Lucas, thanks for taking the time to reply to this :)

Problem is solved now thanks to you guys!!